# applescript works natively but not in Filemaker

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I have a .jar file which runs from terminal and sends a HL7 file to an ip address and port, using minimal lower layer protocol.  This works fine from within Terminal and also works well when scripted in applescript editor using the following script:

```
do shell script "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin/java -jar /Applications/dcm4che-1.4.32/bin/hl7snd.jar mllp://10.0.0.2:2575 /Applications/dcm4che-1.4.32/bin/worklist/file.txt"
```

However when i try and automate this by performing the same applescript within Filemaker pro 12, I get this error:

```
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6//libserver.dylib
```

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same issue in filemaker 11 in mountain lion and I just found a solution. You have to unset the environment variable that filemaker is setting for java. To do this, add this before the java command:

```
unset JAVA_JVM_VERSION
```

So your full script would be:

```
do shell script "unset JAVA_JVM_VERSION;java -jar /Applications/dcm4che-1.4.32/bin/hl7snd.jar mllp://10.0.0.2:2575 /Applications/dcm4che-1.4.32/bin/worklist/file.txt"
```

Comment: That unset command worked a treat!!!  Thanks so much, this has been a really big help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you escape your double-quotes correctly in FileMaker? If you paste the ENTIRE applescript command into the Data Viewer in FileMaker, does it look correct?

It looks like not the entire path is loaded correctly...